# How to implement packet delay with multiple nodes in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, delay

I am doing a python code that has the following:
1- Class nodes, where each node has id as integer and packets [] as an array.
2- main

In the main()

```
Time=0 # set up the time
end= 1000 # the time to end the program
while Time < end:
create_packet() # here some codes that generate a packet by a random node (e.g., node 1) # each packet generated has unique id, timestamp "Time", received time and node id who created it.
send_packet() # here is to generate received time as delay for other nodes (e.g., node 2,,,, etc)
Time +=1 # this movement represents a second
```

#

I need the code to model send_packet() as time delay. If node 1 generates a packet at Time=1,, my code will generate random receive time for node 2 to received the packet e.g., after 3 seconds "here loops" -> that means node 2 will receive it at Time= 4.

During that, node 2 might generate a packet before receiving the packet from node 1..

Each time a node generates or receives a packet will append it to their packets array.. at the end the order of packets at each node can be different of course.

#

My issue is with modeling the delay to only add any generated packet at each node once the received time is reached.

Comment: What does this have to do with multithreading or multiprocessing? It seems to be about simulating a time based system, which can be done perfectly fine in a single thread of a single process.

Comment: Thanks! even for a single process, i still do not know how to simulate propagation delay of a packet as i described above

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_event_simulation You basically need to have a function that, when called, generates a packet and adds to a priority queue, based on how far into the future it should be received. Then, every time you step your time step, you check if one or more events in the priority queue (event list) is due.